# What is the content of ASP.NET FormsAuthentication cookie value?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, .aspxauth

What is the content of ASP.NET FormsAuthentication cookie value? How can I see the real value of the hashed string (in case that I have the decrypted key)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have all necessary information about the content of the authentication cookie

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

Check the section "Forms Authentication Cookies"

`FormsAuthentication.Decrypt` would decrypt the authentication ticket included on the forms authentication cookie.

Comment: Thanks. I never really understand how to find something in MSDN, except throw Google. How did you find this article?

Comment: Well, the first article is a good reference for forms authentication so I have it bookmarked. I knew also about the method FormsAuthentication.Decrypt so it was just a question of looking for it on google. If I'm not sure what I'm looking for I just try different combination of terms on google until I'm lucky :-)

Comment: :) MSDN have a lot of good articles. we just need to explore the way that we can find them.